# calculate an average time with joda time

Tags: java, jodatime

I have many time stamps showing at which time a user entered the room. I want to calculate an average time. The problem occurs when some action happens at night.
I tried to calculate it with milis, but it is wrong.

```
ArrayList<String> times = new ArrayList<String>();

    times.add("00:20:01");
    times.add("00:00:01");
    times.add("23:40:01");
    times.add("23:20:01");
    times.add("23:20:01");
    times.add("00:20:01");
    times.add("23:40:01");
    times.add("23:40:01");
    times.add("00:00:01");
    long commonMillis=0;
    for (String date:times){
        LocalTime time = new LocalTime(date);
        long dayMilis = time.getMillisOfDay();
        commonMillis = commonMillis + dayMilis;
    }
    LocalTime average = new LocalTime(commonMillis/times.size());
```

This code, for example, returns the value `14:08:54.333`. Because the hours `00:00 and 23:00` -- calculated in millis -- are too far from each other.

Please help me to find right way to calculate the average time?

Comment: it is correct in terms of miliseconds, but if I want to know when a person in average enters a room I would like to see something like 00:00 (which is between 23:00 and 01:00)

Comment: Shouldn't you then average Instants instead of LocalTimes. A LocalTime is not a timestamp. An Instant is. There is no way to know if 23:00 is the day before, or the same day as 01:00.

Comment: What is your expected time?

Comment: @flo, my expected time is smth between 23:20 and 00:20. For example, 23:50

Comment: @JBNizet, ok, I dont' have timestamps, I have only times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things:

1. You have to define an offset time:
   If you want an average of times of different days without knowing the day, you have to define an offset time by yourself. This time is used to decide whether a time is belonging to the next day or not.
   This offset time may be derived depending on the values you get.
   Without an offset time, you implicitely use 0 o'clock.
2. Avoid overflows:
   If your `times` list gets longer, you may run into an overflow if a `long` field is not sufficient to store the accumulated value. You can use a data structure which is overflow resistant like `BigInteger` or use the [(culmulative) moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) approach.
3. Wrong result constructor:
   The constructor `LocalTime(long instant)` implicitely uses your local `DateTimeZone` to calculate a local time from an `Instant`. This causes different times when using the same code between different time zones.
   The method you want to use is `LocalTime#fromMillisOfDay`.

Here is an approach considering the above points:

```
    long movingAverage = 0;

    // 1. define offset
    LocalTime offset = new LocalTime("12:00:00");
    long offsetMillis = offset.getMillisOfDay();

    for (String date : times) {
        long sampleMillis = new LocalTime(date).getMillisOfDay();

        // align to offset
        if (sampleMillis < offsetMillis)
            sampleMillis += DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_DAY;

        long diff = sampleMillis - offsetMillis;

        // 2. use moving average
        movingAverage = movingAverage + diff / times.size();
    }

    // 3. avoid LocalTime(long) constructor
    LocalTime result = offset.plusMillis((int) movingAverage);
    System.out.println(result); // 23:48:54.329
```

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach would be to gather the `long` millisecond values in all the dates, add them up and divide them by the number of dates, transforming them back into a LocalDate. You probably need a BigInteger to hold the sum, though.